How to dynamically get operands from a instruction in memory in c++
Im trying to read a instruction from another processes memory and get the operands dynamically. For example if the instruction is MOV how can i know that it has 2 operands?
The process is x64
I tried getting the bytes using ReadProcessMemory but i dont know how many bytes to read for.

You need to read the Intel manuals to get to know the encoding used for the instructions. A fair bit of warning: It's not trivial.

Either you wrestle through the intel assembly manuals, or you use a library like capstone.

Intel PIN and/or the XED disassembler library have C++ interfaces to disassembling / decoding instructions.  https://intelxed.github.io/  x86 machine code is a byte stream: you have to process the byte you read to know how many more to read.

I believe I used zydis once for disassembling.

How many bytes read from another process - usually near page size ( 0x1000) and cache  memory local for not read for every single instruction. How then disasm instructions, another question

There is a practical limit to the size of an x86/x64 instruction, I forget, is it 13 or 15 bytes?
